# Audio intensity in android

Tags: android, speech-recognition

I have created an application for getting the meaning of the English word through voice command. When the user gives the voice gesture i need to show the intensity of the voice on the button where he touch to start the voice recognition. I have 5 different icons and i should show it according to the intensity. So i should find the range of the voice intensity. Is that possible ? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Intensity is an averaged square (sum x^2 / n) of the signal value if signal is encoded in PCM format. You just need to record a signal in PCM and calculate average with a sliding window. See

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html